# Oracle APEX ORDS Limitation on URL template?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-ords

Is there a limitation on the Oracle APEX ords template?

Currently mapping a GET Request to

```
Works : URI Template: /history/{PLATAFORM}/{CONTEXT}/{APPLICAT}/
Works : URI Template: /history/{PLATAFORM}/{CONTEXT}/{APPLICAT}/test/ 

405 Method Not Allowed: URI Template: /history/{PLATAFORM}/{CONTEXT}/{APPLICAT}/{test}/
```

Can't find documentation about this scenario, wonder if it's Oracle APEX limitation/Bug? Or Maybe some configuration somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated,

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No limitations other than please switch to using : syntax over {}. We changed that a while back.

```
-- Generated by Oracle SQL Developer REST Data Services 18.1.0.051.1417
-- Exported REST Definitions from ORDS Schema Version 17.4.0.18.13.50
-- Schema: KLRICE   Date: Tue Apr 03 15:03:00 EDT 2018
--
BEGIN
  ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
      p_enabled             => TRUE,
      p_schema              => 'KLRICE',
      p_url_mapping_type    => 'BASE_PATH',
      p_url_mapping_pattern => 'klrice',
      p_auto_rest_auth      => FALSE);    

  ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE(
      p_module_name    => '/history/',
      p_base_path      => '/history/',
      p_items_per_page =>  25,
      p_status         => 'PUBLISHED',
      p_comments       => NULL);      
  ORDS.DEFINE_TEMPLATE(
      p_module_name    => '/history/',
      p_pattern        => ':PLATFORM/:CONTEXT/:APPLICAT/test',
      p_priority       => 0,
      p_etag_type      => 'HASH',
      p_etag_query     => NULL,
      p_comments       => NULL);
  ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
      p_module_name    => '/history/',
      p_pattern        => ':PLATFORM/:CONTEXT/:APPLICAT/test',
      p_method         => 'GET',
      p_source_type    => 'json/collection',
      p_items_per_page =>  25,
      p_mimes_allowed  => '',
      p_comments       => NULL,
      p_source         => 
'select :PLATFORM,:CONTEXT,:APPLICAT from dual'
      );


  COMMIT; 
END;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response,
I replicated the behaviour you presented, but can't seam to make it work.
I'm running oracle 11 version, It might be the problem ?
Regards